# How to access to dynamic key stored with JQuery data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stored some data of key value inside an html element using the following:

```
$('#newItem').data("metadata", data);
```

this data contains few keys that are name like `img0 img1 img2 img3`

The number of images are not know in advance , but i'm getting in another key the number of images that exist in the key value data.

I'm trying to loop over the stored data and pull these value with something like this but it obviously not working:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < numOfPic; i++ ) 
    {       
        var img = $(item).data("metadata").itemPic+i;
    }
```

is there any way to convert the `itemPic+i` to a key that i can use?

Comment: Just use square brackets notation: `...[itemPic+i]`

Comment: Syntax error on token ".", Identifier expected after this token

Comment: @USer22999299 he meant `$(item).data("metadata")[itemPic+i];` I suppose

Comment: @Amit Joki Exactly:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use square brackets as suggested by @hindmost:

```
var images = $(item).data("metadata"),
    itemPic = 'img';
for ( var i = 0; i < numOfPic; i++ ) 
{       
    var img = images[itemPic+i]; // or images["img" + 1]
}
```

And it is always good practice to run a DOM search once and cache the search instead of doing a search for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: var img = $(item).data("metadata").itemPic0; is working.
var img = $(item).data("metadata")
console.log(img[itemPic0]) - not working

Comment: Try `console.log( img['itemPic0'] )`

Comment: Usually when using square brackets, you have to **quote** a string literal, when not quoted, it is assumed to be a **variable**.